# Getting Unsupported Media Type when trying to access POST Json consumer endpoint developed using Jersey

Tags: java, json, jersey, jax-rs, postman

I am getting this error when I try to execute my POST webservice methods:

[image: 415 error]

I am using Postman to send the request:

[image: postman-post-json request]

My entity is below:

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@Table(name = "bandeiras")
public class BandeiraCartao extends EntidadeBase {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 5944226798248177637L;

  @XmlElement
  @Column(length = 60, nullable = false)
  private String nome;

  @XmlElement
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private Integer codigoImagem;

  //getters and setters//
}
```

This is the superclass:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class EntidadeBase implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -3912856473903279467L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@PodamStrategyValue(value = NullStrategy.class)
private Long id;

  @Column(name = "cadastro_data", nullable = false)
  @PodamStrategyValue(value = PastDateStrategy.class)
  private LocalDate dataCadastro;

  @Column(name = "modificado_data", nullable = false)
  @PodamStrategyValue(value = PastDateStrategy.class)
  private LocalDate dataModificacao;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  @PodamBooleanValue(boolValue = false)
  private Boolean modificado;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  @PodamBooleanValue(boolValue = true)
  private Boolean ativo;

  //getters and setters//
}
```

and finally there is the endpoint method I am calling:

```
@Path("/bandeira")
public class BandeiraCartaoResource extends AbstractResource<BandeiraCartao> {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 7080737992715054407L;

  @POST
  @Override
  @Transactional
  public Response inserir(@NotNull BandeiraCartao entidade) {
      return super.inserir(entidade);
  }

  ...
  }
```

I added Genson dependency in order to dont have to provide a MessageBodyWritter implementation of my own.
I also added MOXy jersey dependency trying to solve this issue, but it didnt work.
As additional information, its running on tomcat 8.
Any clue guys?

Comment: Did you set the `Content-Type:application/json` header? You should add a `Consumes("application/json")` annotation on your method also.

Comment: I didnt the first step, anyway, my AbstractResource contains the annotation Produces and Consumes, them are both Inherited, so it should propagate to all my endpoints. I will try it anyways, thanks for the tip. @peeskillet

Comment: It works, you were right about adding     Content-Type:application/json      to the header, you should post it as an answer, I would gladly accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I just tested...

Simple using the <kbd>JSON</kbd> raw type in post man doesn't set the the required header. You can click the <kbd>Preview</kbd> button and it will show you a preview of the entire request, including headers. What you need is a header `Content-Type:application/json`. You will see it is not there in the preview window. You can set it though with the <kbd>Headers</kbd> button on the main screen. Just set the `Header` to `Content-Type` and the `value` to `application/json`.

**UPDATE**

If you open up the Chrome developer tools and make the request (select the "Network/XHR" tab), you can see the default headers that gets set with the XHR request. It's actually more than just the `Cache-Control` you see in the Postman preview window. You will see it explicitly sets the content type to `text/plain`

[image]

Comment: Yeah I think that JSON selection in the drop down is just for assisted formatting and syntax highlighting. That's the only benefit I could see from it :-)

Comment: Probably, but its confusing, they should make that clear